# PowerShell script Hangman game

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to develop the hangman game in PowerShell. All goes well in my script but there is an logical error in the game. I want to put the check, that when user enter the same word twice. It simple gives error ! 
For example : The Word "Football".
If user enter Letter 'F' more then 1 times it should give error message.
 Here is my code :

```
$random = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 5;
$names="America","Iran","Poland","Cat","PowerShell ";
$arrname= $names[$random];
$arrname.ToCharArray();
$ntp="0","1";
$arrlen = $arrname.Length;
clear;

Write-Host "---------Guess the word--------------";

Write-Host "Length is  : " $arrname.Length;
$life=3;
do{
Write-Host "Lifes Remain " $life;
$rnd= Read-Host "Guess the   word ";

if($flag2 -le 1)
{
 $flag=0;
}
else
{
$life--;
}  
for($i=0;$i -lt $arrname.Length; $i++)
{

if($rnd -eq $arrname[$i] )
{
$flag =1;
$arrlen --;
}
}
if($flag -eq 0 )
{

$life--;

}

if($arrlen -eq 0)
{

Write-Host  $arrname;
Write-Host " ************  You WIN  ********************";
break;

}

if($life -eq 0)
{
Write-Host " ------------- You LOST ------------"
break;
}
$p++;
}
while(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this should get you well on your way, to keep track of the letters add them to an array `$guesses=@()` then check if they have already used a letter using contains the letter `$guesses -contains $guessLetter`

```
$random = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 5;
$names="America","Iran","Poland","Cat","PowerShell";
$targetWord = $names[$random];
[Char[]]$wordProgress =  "_" * $targetWord.Length
clear;

Write-Host "---------Guess the word--------------";

$life=3;
$guesses=@()
do
{
    do
    {
        Write-Host "[$($targetWord.Length)] $wordProgress";
        Write-Host "Lifes Remain " $life

        $guessLetter = Read-Host "Guess a letter:"
        if ($guesses -contains $guessLetter)
        {
            "Try another letter!"
        }
    } while ($guesses -contains $guessLetter) 

    $guesses+=$guessLetter
    $guesses -join ','

    $foundLetter = $false
    for($i=0;$i -lt $targetWord.Length; $i++)
    {
        if($guessLetter -like $targetWord[$i] )
        {
            $wordProgress[$i] = $guessLetter
            $foundLetter=$true
        }
    }

    if(!$foundLetter)
    {
        $life--;
    }

    if($($wordProgress -join '') -like $targetWord)
    {
        Write-Host $targetWord;
        Write-Host " ************  You WIN  ********************";
        break;
    }

}
while($life -gt 0)
if ($life -eq 0)
{
Write-Host " ------------- You LOST ------------"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the little spin **I made** on the coding, I decided to give 5 lives and added 5 more words to the word bank (this is the first time I did this without needing help *f i n a l l y*.)! IF it bugs and wont let you run it try copying the original answer without my coding added onto it then it'll run or after you are done editing the code go down to the bottom without clicking and try running it.

```
$random = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 10;
$names="America","Iran","Poland","Cat","PowerShell","Cow","How","Such","Dog","Dough";
$targetWord = $names[$random];
[Char[]]$wordProgress =  "_" * $targetWord.Length
clear;

Write-Host "---------Guess the word--------------";

$life=5;
$guesses=@()
do
{
    do
    {
        Write-Host "[$($targetWord.Length)] $wordProgress";
        Write-Host "Lifes Remain " $life

        $guessLetter = Read-Host "Guess a letter:"
        if ($guesses -contains $guessLetter)
        {
            "Try another letter!"
        }
    } while ($guesses -contains $guessLetter) 

    $guesses+=$guessLetter
    $guesses -join ','

    $foundLetter = $false
    for($i=0;$i -lt $targetWord.Length; $i++)
    {
        if($guessLetter -like $targetWord[$i] )
        {
            $wordProgress[$i] = $guessLetter
            $foundLetter=$true
        }
    }

    if(!$foundLetter)
    {
        $life--;
    }

    if($($wordProgress -join '') -like $targetWord)
    {
        Write-Host $targetWord;
        Write-Host " ************  You WIN  ********************";
        break;
    }

}
while($life -gt 0)
if ($life -eq 0)
{
Write-Host " ------------- You LOST ------------"
}
```